# android webview videos not loading

Tags: android, video, webview

My app loads site into WebView and so far everything is working perfectly except for video.
When I try to load video directly into the URL nothing happens, and on LogCat it just says that the DNS query was forwarded, but doesn't return an error.
I don't see that there's a permission that I need for Media to add in the manifest so I don't know where to go next with this problem.. the videos load fine directly on the site, but not in app mode.
Please help with the next step to troubleshoot this issue